# Can't parse malformed JSON from Twilio API

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, twilio

I've spent 4 hours trying to parse a simple JSON from Twilio.

The flow is:

1. Text message containing `magnet` link
2. Twilio proxies request to my serverless function on cloud
3. Parse req. to get the value

## Twilio Studio UI

[image]

## Code

```js
....
var app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

module.exports.magnet = async (event) => {
  let requestBody = ''
  try {
    requestBody = JSON.parse(event.body)
    requestBody = requestBody["magnet"]
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
  await beginAuth(requestBody
....
```

I'm just getting malformed JSON. When I play around with `stringify` and `parse` together, I just either get malformed error or I get an added `\r` escape character, which also causes issues.

Not sure if this is just Twilio or me. I just want the magnet link as a string.

I tried

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.body))
```

but that also didn't help.

#### Sample Payload

```js
{"magnet": "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:9970E5BF56EDDB06024EF1311109865B893C8EB4&dn=Westworld+-+Season+3+-+Mp4+x264+AC3+1080p&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A80%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.zer0day.to%3A1337%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.pirateparty.gr%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Feddie4.nl%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fcoppersurfer.tk%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.pirateparty.gr%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Feddie4.nl%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.zer0day.to%3A1337%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fcoppersurfer.tk%3A6969%2Fannounce"}
```

Comment: Could you provide output of `console.log(event.body)`, just before ```requestBody = JSON.parse(event.body)``` ?

Comment: Did my answer help John or are you still experiencing problems?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio sends the body usually formatted as a [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), i.e. you have to decode it like this:

```
const querystring = require('querystring');
requestBody = querystring.parse(event.body);
requestBody = requestBody['magnet']
```

To verify that it's sent as a query string simply print the `event.body` after receiving it, in your example it should look similar to this:

```
magnet=magnet%3A%3Fxt%3Durn%3Abtih%3A9970E5BF56EDDB06024EF1311109865B893C8EB4%26dn%3DWestworld%2B-%2BSeason%2B3%2B-%2BMp4%2Bx264%2BAC3%2B1080p%26tr%3Dudp%253A%252F%252Ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%253A6969%252Fannounce%26tr%3Dudp%253A%252F%252Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%253A6969%252Fannounce%26tr%3Dudp%253A%252F%252Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%253A80%252Fannounce%26tr%3Dudp%253A%252F%252Ftracker.opentrackr.org%253A1337%252Fannounce%26tr%3Dudp%253A%252F%252Ftracker.zer0day.to%253A1337%252Fannounce%26tr%3Dudp%253A%252F%252Ftracker.pirateparty.gr%253A6969%252Fannounce%26tr%3Dudp%253A%252F%252Feddie4.nl%253A6969%252Fannounce%26tr%3Dudp%253A%252F%252Fcoppersurfer.tk%253A6969%252Fannounce%26tr%3Dudp%253A%252F%252Ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%253A6969%26tr%3Dudp%253A%252F%252Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%253A6969%26tr%3Dudp%253A%252F%252Ftracker.opentrackr.org%253A1337%26tr%3Dudp%253A%252F%252Ftracker.pirateparty.gr%253A6969%26tr%3Dudp%253A%252F%252Feddie4.nl%253A6969%26tr%3Dudp%253A%252F%252Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%253A80%26tr%3Dudp%253A%252F%252Ftracker.zer0day.to%253A1337%252Fannounce%26tr%3Dudp%253A%252F%252Ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%253A6969%252Fannounce%26tr%3Dudp%253A%252F%252Fcoppersurfer.tk%253A6969%252Fannounce
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Although, I'm not forwarding it as a query string. I'm forwarding the data on the request body via http post

Comment: Is there a reason you're proxying via a Twilio Studio Flow? You could consume the SMS directly with the Twilio Function. Also how does the complete call in your Twilio Studio Flow look like? And how does a print of the full event look like? Please post it. Do you see any irregularities there?

Comment: I got it working by better parsing the input data, needing to run regex to replace special characters before doing JSON.parse as it seemed carriage return was breaking the parse in my express app.